# Why does an empty loop use so much GPU (OpenGL)?

Tags: c++, opengl, mingw-w64

I am trying to create a GUI library using the modern OpenGL. But I notice that, when other games and programs are using ~16-20% of my GPU time (when the game is not started, on the main menu) my simple glClear() and swapping buffers calls use ~25-26% (on fullscreen mode).

I am using glfw and glew with the following code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main() {
    if(!glfwInit()) return -1;

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, false);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, false);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    //glfwWindowHint(GLFW_REFRESH_RATE, 60);

    GLFWwindow *window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, "Untitled Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if(window == nullptr) return -2;

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK) return -3;
    //glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

For instance, Hearts of Iron IV launcher consumes about 6-7% of my GPU time, whereas the program I run with the code above uses about 13% of my GPU time.

In fact, my program starts with 4%, and goes up to 13% after a few seconds.

I have NVIDIA's GeForce GTX 980M and Intel HD Graphics 4600 (which uses ~4% with the above code, unlike NVIDIA).

Is there something wrong with my computer or is it something about the compiler/api?

By the way, I've tested both with and without the commented sections and the results were very similar. I also tried using OpenGL 4 but it had no affect at all.

VSync is enabled both for NVIDIA and Intel GPU.

Comment: You should check your error return codes. Might give you a hint.

Comment: For exampe if glfwSwapInterval failed for some reason.

Comment: That's a strange resolution (1/4 of Full HD), it shouldn't be any 13% but there will be some performance penalty for scaling up to the actual resolution.

Comment: @ZanLynx There are no errors, all the functions serve as they were expected.

Comment: "In fact, my program starts with 4%, and goes up to 13% after a few seconds." Yeah, because the GPU goes into powersave and clocks down. "GPU Utilization" is just a meaningless number without context

Answer (score 7):

There are a couple reasons for the high GPU use you're seeing in this (seemingly) simple program, but the biggest reason is...

### This is not an empty loop

Consider, for example, the one line function call you've made at the end of your loop: `glfwSwapBuffers(window);`. This is the function call responsible for instructing the GPU to discard the currently rendered frame and render the next one. Even with no actual objects to draw, this still requires the GPU to redraw several million pixels (depending on your monitor size), and since your loop will only ever wait on user input, the loop will execute as quickly as it is physically capable; on my computer, this loop on its own will run at about 13khz.

Of course, even if you were to fill this loop with actual work to do, it would still be running as fast as possible, and although it'll probably be slower than 13khz once it has actual work to do, it'll probably be way faster than your monitor's refresh rate.

### If you enable vertical sync or add a deliberate wait, the GPU usage will be more reasonable

The simplest solution is to just enable Vertical Sync, meaning the GPU will only render when the monitor is ready for the next frame, at 60hz (or 120hz, or 144hz, whatever rate your monitor is running at).

Your post *claims* that vertical sync is enabled, but you already have the function that would do it commented out. Uncomment `glfwSwapInterval(1);`, and you should see GPU usage dramatically drop, even if there isn't any rendering the GPU needs to do. If you have an FPS display, you should see the FPS drop from whatever it was at down to a relatively flat 60hz; or 16.67 ms frame time if that's what you track instead.

Comment: Question says "I've tested both with and without the commented sections and the results were very similar"

Comment: I have also enabled VSync from the driver settings.